# storm rebalance command not updating the number of workers for a topology

Tags: apache-storm, scheduling

I tried executing the following command for storm 1.1.1:

storm [topologyName] -n [number_of_worker]

The command successfully runs but the number of workers remain unchanged. I tried reducing the number of workers too. That also didn't work.

I have no clue whats happening. Any pointer will be helpful.

FYI:
i have implemented custom scheduling?. Is it because of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check Storm's source code behind that CLI. Or code the re-balance (tested against 1.0.2):

```
RebalanceOptions rebalanceOptions = new RebalanceOptions();
rebalanceOptions.set_num_workers(newNumWorkers);
Nimbus.Client.rebalance("foo", rebalanceOptions);
```